# BSOD while turning on Wireguard VPN (ONLY with specific Wifi connection)

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, vpn, bsod

I have two Wifi connections.
One is from my Android tethered connection and the other is from a local broadband provider.
I have windows 10 and Wireguard VPN service.
In one computer I connected to Phone Wify and turned on the VPN and it worked. But in the same computer, when I connected to broadband wify, and turned on VPN the Windows is showing BSOD with tcpip.sys error.

In my second computer both connections working and VPN also works without any issue.

My doubt is if it was a problem with driver, shouldn't it show BSON while connecting to Phone wify?

Comment: Very odd. Try these steps to repair system files. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e

Comment: Consider also, possible driver issues and issues with tcpip.sys. https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/tcpip-sys-blue-screen-of-death-on-windows-10-7-8/

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I tried both technics mentioned in the solutions. But the issue is not going away.